# Scala - Import error

Tags: scala

Buenas noches.

Cuando importo un singleton object de una classe dentro del mismo folder, me sale este error, miren.

En esta clase llamada Summer.scala, es donde trato de importar el Singleton Object de la clase ChecksumAccumulator

```
import ChecksumAccumulator.calculate

 object Summer{
 def main(args: Array[String]): Unit= {

    for (arg <- args)
        println(arg + " : " +  calculate(arg))


 }

}
```

Clase ChecksumAccumulator, con su Singleton Object ChecksumAccumulator

```
object ChecksumAccumulator {


/*
     When a singleton object shares the same name
     with a class, it is called that class's companion object. 
*/

 private val cache = mutable.Map.empty[String, Int]


 def calculate(s: String): Int =

     if (cache.contains(s))
        cache(s)
     else {
         val acc = new ChecksumAccumulator

         //The object with the same name of the class can acces to the private members.
         //println(acc.sum)
         for (c <- s)
            acc.add(c.toByte)
         val cs = acc.checksum()
         cache += (s -> cs)
         cs
    }
 def showMap() : Unit = {
    for(base:String <- cache.keys)
        println(cache(base))

 }
//def showMap(): String = { var cadena = cache("Every value is an object.") +  " "+ cache("Every value is an object. per second time!!");  cadena  }
```

}

Me sale este error:

scala Summer.scala

Summer.scala:8: error: not found: object ChecksumAccumulator
import ChecksumAccumulator.calculate
       ^
Summer.scala:14: error: not found: value calculate
                        println(arg + " : " +  calculate(arg))
                                               ^
two errors found

Comment: Por favor no adjuntes imagenes de tu codigo, copia y pega tu codigo, para que sea mas facil ayudarte

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario, lo tendré presente para futuros post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es el error de que no tienes compilado el fichero `ChecksumAccumulator.scala`. Cuando divides el código en varios ficheros no puedes seguir usando scala como lenguaje de scripting, tendrás que aprender cómo compilar con `scalac` o, más recomendable, con `sbt`.

Prueba con

```
$ scalac Summer.scala ChecksumAccumulator.scala
$ scala Summer
```

Comment: Muchas, pero muchas gracias, de verdad, estoy muy agradecido! Que tengas un feliz dia, si me funciono!